# Does termcal work with datetime?

Tags: datetime, termcal

I'm using both `datetime` and `termcal` together in a document, but this seems to cause an error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{datetime,termcal}
\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{6/1/15}{2}
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{\monthname. \thedate}
\calday[Monday]{\classday}% Monday
\skipday% Tuesday
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}%Wednesday
\skipday% Thursday
\skipday % Friday
\skipday\skipday% Weekend
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error message from the console:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/termcal/termcal.sty:135: LaTeX Error: Command \monthname already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.135         \or Nov\or Dec\fi}
```

Comment: Yes, they conflict because they each define a command called `\monthname` and I personally have not idea how to make these two packages load together.  Perhaps one of the `wizards` will have a possible solution.

Comment: I checked the documentation for `etoolbox` and I think you could use this to patch either `datetime` or `termcal` to prevent the conflict.  However, I have never used this package.  I would recommend you draft a new question asking how to use etoolbox to patch one of those packages to eliminate the conflict.  And then just delete this question.

Comment: You can `\let\monthname\relax` or use `etoolbox`'s `\undef`.  Not sure which package has the command you want to keep and which you want to `\relax`, though. (There may also be other unexpected consequences in a complex document.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `datetime` package has now been replaced with [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2). One of the reasons for replacing the package with a new one (rather than simply modifying the old one) was to avoid these types of conflicts by ensuring that most of the commands have a prefix. (If I'd simply updated `datetime` all the old commands, such as `\monthname`, would have had to be retained for backward compatibility and the problem would still remain.)

The base `datetime2` package only has numerical date styles, so you can do:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{datetime2,termcal}
\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{6/1/15}{2}
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{\monthname. \thedate}
\calday[Monday]{\classday}% Monday
\skipday% Tuesday
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}%Wednesday
\skipday% Thursday
\skipday % Friday
\skipday\skipday% Weekend
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

This will just use `termcal`'s definition of `\monthname`. Language dependent dates are in the [datetime2 language modules](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/). For example, for English, you'd need to additionally install [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english). This will be loaded by `datetime2` if the language is detected. Each language module comes with its own month name command. For the English language module the command is called `\DTMenglishmonthname`. This takes one compulsory argument, which is the month number. So if you prefer to use this instead of `termcal`'s `\monthname` you can do:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,english]{article}
\usepackage{datetime2,termcal}
\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{6/1/15}{2}
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{\DTMenglishmonthname{\value{month}}. \thedate}
\calday[Monday]{\classday}% Monday
\skipday% Tuesday
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}%Wednesday
\skipday% Thursday
\skipday % Friday
\skipday\skipday% Weekend
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

If you get an undefined control sequence for `\DTMenglishmonthname`, then that probably means that the language module isn't installed. (There should be a warning about it in the log file.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by writing that `datetime` is obsolete and probably it's not a good idea to use it.  The [author says](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime?lang=en) it is being replaced by `datetime2`.  I'm not sure if the latter has the same conflicts.

The two packages (`datetime` and `termcal`) do indeed conflict, as mentioned in the comments.  The solution that Jon suggests in his comment resolves the conflict but does not produce the correct result (you won't see June's calendar, unless it's actually June when you run LaTeX).  The reason is that the two macros are semantically incompatible:

1. The `\monthname` defined in `datetime` takes an optional argument, which is the number of the month (1-12).  Its value defaults to the current month.
2. The `\monthname` defined in `termcal` takes no argument.  It expands to the name of the month whose number is contained in the `\c@month` variable.

I assume that the desired behaviour is to make `termcal` use `\monthname` as defined in `datetime`.  Here's what I propose:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{termcal}
%% forget about termcal's version
\let\monthname\relax

\usepackage{datetime}
%% rename datetime's version
\let\dtmonthname\monthname

%% and make a new version that behaves as termcal's but uses datetime's...
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\monthname{\dtmonthname[\c@month]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{6/1/15}{2}
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{\monthname. \thedate}
\calday[Monday]{\classday}% Monday
\skipday% Tuesday
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}%Wednesday
\skipday% Thursday
\skipday % Friday
\skipday\skipday% Weekend
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: result]